# How do i use the Qt libraries 4.7.1 for Windows (VS 2008) on VS 2010?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, qt, qt4

i've downloaded the Qt libraries 4.7.1 for Windows (VS 2008)
and i would like to use it in visual studio 2010,
any ideas on how to do so?

thanks in advance

Dante

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use Qt libraries compiled with VC++ 2010. The VS2008-compiled versions link to a different version of the MS Visual C++ Runtime.

Unfortunately, that most likely means downloading the source and building libraries yourself.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to recompile them from source or download binaries that have been built with VS2010 as the implementation of some parts of the VS2010 C++ standard library has changed.